# Datetime Picker Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

Below is a page code of my custom plugin  where I am trying to use jquery datetime picker.
The picker script was taken from [this link](http://razum.si/jQuery-calendar/TimeCalendar.html). But due to some reason I am getting an Error message saying "jQuery("#calendar1, #calendar2").calendar is not a function". I have checked that the files required are included correctly and before the custom code. But still there is this error.

```
<?php
function list_my_styles() {  // ADDING THE SCRIPTS
$plugin_url = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my_custom_datepicker/';
wp_register_style('my-addon-datepicker-css',$plugin_url.'jquery-calendar.css');
wp_enqueue_style('my-addon-datepicker-css');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('calendar_plugin',$plugin_url.'jquery-calendar.js');
wp_enqueue_script('calendar_plugin');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','list_my_styles');

function my_custom_datetime_script() {  // ADDING THE JQUERY SCRIPT
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#calendar1, #calendar2").calendar();
        jQuery("#calendar1_alert").click(function(){alert(popUpCal.parseDate(jQuery('#calendar1').val()))});
    });
</script>
<?php   
}
add_action('wp_head','my_custom_datetime_script');
function custom_datetime_picker_area() {
?>

<input type="text" id="calendar1" class="calendarFocus"/>
<input type="button" id="calendar1_alert" value="Alert datetime object"/>
<?php   
}
add_shortcode('my_datepicker','custom_datetime_picker_area');
?>
```

Any Help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I use in my plugin:

```
        /* add jquery ui datepicker and theme */
        global $wp_scripts;
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
        $ui = $wp_scripts->query('jquery-ui-core');
        $url = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/{$ui->ver}/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.all.css";
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-redmond', $url, false, $ui->ver);
```

The CDN I'm using has all of the available themes to choose from as well.

Then on my form page i use:

```
        <label for="date_of" style="width: 135px !important;">Presentation Date
        <?php echo '<img src="'.$this->pluginurl.'images/help.png"
        title="Enter the Presentation date here." />';?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="date_of" name="date_of" value="" />
```

and in:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#date_of').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
       });
    });
```

I load plugin.js file with register/enqueue_script which contains the document.ready function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I wanted. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The error means it can not find this function , which in turns means either : 
1 - it can not find the script , or 
2 - you are trying to execute the script before it is loaded ..

One thing I did not understand - where is this code going in your plugin ??

Anyhow, first verify that you have a `wp_head()` and `wp_head()` action (template tags)  in your THEME where you test the plugin, Then , also try to move the action to the footer ...

```
    function my_custom_datetime_script() {  // ADDING THE JQUERY SCRIPT
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#calendar1, #calendar2").calendar();
            jQuery("#calendar1_alert").click(function(){alert(popUpCal.parseDate(jQuery('#calendar1').val()))});
        });
    </script>
    <?php   
    }

add_action('wp_footer','my_custom_datetime_script');
```